# How to insert multiple rows to mysql using php form when checkbox is ticked in the row

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I Have a PHP form where I am sending to MYSQL DB fields: ID, NAME, CITY
I have another form where I am editing whole list.
What id like to do is to populate the same NAME (choosing from list) to every row when checkbox is ticked.

Form.php

```php
<form method="post" action="submit.php" >
<select name="name" id="name"><option type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>"><?php echo $name ?></option></select>
<select name="city" id="city"><option type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $city ?>"><?php echo $city ?></option></select>
<input type="checkbox" name="check[<?php echo $id ?>]" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
<button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
</form>
```

submit.php

```php
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check'] as $key=>$value){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['id'][$key];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
        mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE table SET name='$name', city='$city' WHERE id=$id");
}
```

It would be awsome to tick checkbox to those rows where i want to have the same defined NAME and submit it.

[image]

Comment: `checkbox` will be posted as an array.

Comment: by default check box store is in array format... it will post in array format... Use name="check_box" instead of name="check[<?php echo $id ?>]"

Comment: didnt helped as well

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example, hope it will help you.You cannot have id value in option tag, you can only have value.

```
    <form method="post" action="submit.php">
        <select name="name" id="name">
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        </select>
        <select name="city" id="city">
          <option value="Athens">Athens</option>
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check_box" />
        <button type="submit" name="update">Update</button>
    </form>    

<?php
    if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

        $check_box_checked = isset($_POST['check_box']);

        if($check_box_checked){
            echo "Checked";
        }else{
            echo "Un Checked";
        }

        $id = $_POST['city'];
        echo $id;

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo $name;

        //mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE table SET name='$name', city='$city' WHERE id=$id");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: unfortunately this answer doesnt work. I want to tick a checkbox for specific rows, to which i'd like to change the same NAME from the list. When i hit update only those rows will get the same chosen name where checkbox was ticked. Check my screenshot.

Comment: @Lucas you cannot have `option` tag with type text and name, you can only have value in each option.Also, if you want to have multiple values in each checkbox, you have to concat the `id | city | name` and then split it.